# Inherit thread class in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have some questions about inheriting thread class.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, num):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.num = num

  def run(self):
    print("Thread", self.num)
    time.sleep(1)
```

why can't I only override the run method? 
The Python document of [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html) mention that ***"The Thread class represents an activity that is run in a separate thread of control. There are two ways to specify the activity: by passing a callable object to the constructor, or by overriding the run() method in a subclass."***

Why does the above example code override the constructor also?

Comment: What is the source of the code you have posted?

Comment: Because you typically need to pass the data to work on to `run()` somehow? And doing it explicitly via constructor and class fields is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is overridden to pass the `num` parameter from the place where instance of `MyThread` is created to the `run` method.

Note that you do not call `run` method directly so you can't pass any parameters to it unless you store them in constructor.

If you don't need to pass parameters you can override only `run` method.